# Display single image using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

> ```
> <?php
> if (!empty($images)) {
>     foreach ($images as $image):
>         echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['Image']['img_file'], array('alt' => 'Gallery Image'));
>     ?>
> <br/>
> <?php
>         echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $image['Image']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $image['Image']['id']));
>     endforeach;
> }else {
>     echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Profile Image', true), array('action' => 'add'));
> }
> ?>
> ```

Hi How do I only show a single image from the database without using the foreach loop. For example, i have an image in the database "default.jpg". if user did not add any image, a default image will be displayed. then if the user chose to add a profile image, the default image will be replaced to the new image the user selected. then if the user has deleted their profile image, the default image will be displayed.

Comment: dont use DS in url links! DS is for the file system. simply use /

Comment: He means don't use `'uploads'.DS.'images'` in URLs. Use `'uploads/images'` instead. DS can change according to the system that's running the server, but URLs always use `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php
  if (!empty($images)) {
   foreach ($images as $image):
       echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['Image']['img_file'],    array('alt' => 'Gallery Image'));
?>
<br/>
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $image['Image']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $image['Image']['id']));
endforeach;
}else {
 echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . 'default.jpg',    array('alt' => 'Gallery Image'));
 echo "<br/>";
echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Profile Image', true), array('action' => 'add'));
}
?>
```